# search JSON datatype value in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have tried this to get records matching value 1 in products_applicable column

```
Coupon::whereJsonContains('products_applicable',['1'])->get();
```

how do we get records using dynamic value like $value instead of ['1'], i have tried this

```
Coupon::whereJsonContains('products_applicable',[$value])->get();
```

and

```
Coupon::whereJsonContains('products_applicable',$value)->get();
```

Nothing Worked>>>> How do i get all records matching $value in products_applicable column which is json datatype

also I want to merge this  2 codes  **like i want all records having null value at products_applicable and having $value**

```
$data= Coupon::whereNull('products_applicable')->get();
Coupon::whereJsonContains('products_applicable',$value)->get();
```

. hope anyone can help me..

Comment: You forgot to tell what didn't work exactly :)

Comment: how to search a value in json array?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by passing an array to `whereJsonContins()`method.
For example:

```
$value = [1, 2, 3];

$data= Coupon::whereNull('products_applicable')
    ->orWhereJsonContains('products_applicable', $value)->get();
```

**Notice**: You can pass `whereJsonContains()` method both an array or a value (string or integer).